# Error when validating iOS App

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, nib

I am trying to publish an iOS application, however I receive these error when I try to validate my build:

```
Nib file 'Main-iPad~.nib' was not found. Please ensure the specified file is included in the bundle with any required device modifiers appended to the filename

Invalid Info.plist: The Info.plist may contain either UIMainStoryboardFile or NSMainNibFile, but it must not contain both keys. For more information, refer to the Information Property List Key Reference.
```

Comment: Have you read the error and had a look at the info.plist file? Does it contain both UIMainStoryboardFile and NSMainNibFile?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It seems you have some stale entry in your Info.plist. Inspect it and delete the "Main nib file base name". Also make sure the nib file is not included in your target.

I assume you are using storyboard, so you need to remove the nib file.

Comment: In my info.plist file I had this: <key>NSMainNibFile~ipad</key><string></string>. Had to delete it completely from the file.