# Nib file Main-iPad~ipad.nib' was not found

Tags: xcode, ipad, nib

I'm trying to validate an iPhone app, which is ready to be released after validation. Xcode insists that there must be an ipad file for it though, any suggestions? I would upload a photo, but I don't have enough rep, due to me just starting Stack Overflow.

Comment: Found the answer here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20886973/error-when-validating-ios-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be, that you have choosen in your Project Settings, that it should be an "Universal" App, if so. Xcode wants two storyboards, one for the iPhone, one for iPad.

If this is the problem, just open your project settings and remove the "Universal" and change it to "iPhone".

Comment: Hi there, the app itself is already an iPhone exclusive app, it is iPhone rather than universal.

Answer (score 1):

Likely there is a Main nib file designated in your info.plist file, but you have this resource not included in your application.

If you delete this entry in the info.plist file, it will be fixed.